# How to resolve "NewConnectionError: Failed to establish new connection [Errno 11001] " in pycharm when calling external API

Tags: python, api, http, networking, proxy

I have been trying to fix this issue for 3 days now. I am using my corporate computer and trying to access an external API.

This is the code I am running

```
import requests

headers = {
            'Authorization': 'bearer <token>'
             'Accept' : 'application/scim+json'
}

proxy = {"HTTPS_PROXY" : "http:// <proxy_ip>:proxy_port"

r= requests.get(<URL>,headers=header,proxies=proxy)
```

I proceed to get the error

"NewConnectionError: Failed to establish new connection [Errno 11001] "

If I add this line,
 `os.environ[https] = "http:// <proxy_ip>:proxy_port"`
at the top to set the enviroment proxy instead of passing it in the get request, then I get a 407
proxy error.

The thing, is, this works in CURL from cmd, but not in pycharm through a python script.

Answer (score 0):

Due to lack of information, I can not reproduce the error. But I would like to share one experience. In a project I need to integrate a third party API, curl was working fine but python was not. I took some outside help but from python it was not working. I also contacted support but they didn't have any python people, their service was built on node.js. So no luck! I used subprocess as that program was a desktop app.
You can use this tool https://curl.trillworks.com/ to convert your curl to python and check the result. Happy debugging!